# Как задать ЧПУ вид всех параметров в url Yii2?

Tags: yii2

вот так выглядит ссылка моя на данный момент.
basic/shop/products?id_category=9&products_per_page=9&sort_direction=DESC&sort_type=name&page=2&per-page=9

хотелось бы видеть ссылку вида:
basic/shop/products/id_category/9/products_per_page=9/sort_direction/DESC/sort_type/name/page/2/per-page/9

когда я в правила прописал: 
'shop/products/id_category/' => 'shop/products'

то параметр ссылки id_category обрел требуемый вид, но я все еще не могу понять, каким образом я могу привести все параметры в URL к требуемому виду и вохможно ли это средствами фреймворка?

Comment: Добрый день. В Вашем случае поможет создание своего класса. Вот, изучайте. 1) https://elisdn.ru/blog/68/urlmanager-and-urlrule-conversation. 2) https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB-

Comment: Спасибо большое.